# How to handle a select that comes up empty?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How would I handle returning `0` if `select` comes up empty when searching an array of hashes?

I have the following following line that looks for the `created` key within an array of hashes:

```
array.select{|key| key[:created] == Date.yesterday }.first[:amount]
```

Then, it returns the `amount` key when it finds the record.

The problem is, if it can't find a record where `key[:created] == Date.yesterday` then I get this error:

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's what the array of hashes looks like:

```
[
   {:created=>"2014-01-20", :amount=>123},
   {:created=>"2014-01-21", :amount=>456},
   {:created=>"2014-01-22", :amount=>789}
]
```

Comment: Could you make it a hash of hashes instead of an array, and use `new` to set the default as a hash with no `:created` date and an `:amount` of zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) instead of `select`, `find` returns the first object in the enumerable that satisfies the block:

```
found = array.find { |hash| hash[:created] == Date.yesterday }
amount = found ? found[:amount] : DEFAULT_VALUE
```

If you are using Rails you could use the [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try) method:

```
array.find { |hash| ... }.try(:[], :amount)
```

**Update**: note that the comparison between a `String` and a `Date` is doomed to fail, you have to convert the date to a properly formatted string or vice versa. In my example I've assumed that `hash[:created]` is a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom I use is

```
res = array.select{|key| key[:created] == Date.yesterday }
res.blank? ? nil : res.first[:amount]
```

Sure, it's not a pretty one liner, but it defends against nil. `blank?` is I think part of activesupport, but you could roll your own easily.